# URL Rewrite Force to https except one domain

Tags: ssl, https, url-rewriting, web-config

First of all, I need to say that after hours googling, I could not find a way to to get the result I need.
Here's the problem:

1. I have 2 domains for my website, for example: (foo.com) and
   (bar.com)
2. I need foo.com domain to be redirected to HTTPS
3. I need bar.com to remain on its HTTP and do NOT redirect to HTTPS

I have tried many rules, but none of them did the job. for example:

```
<rule name="Force HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^(www.)?bar.com$$" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should redirect foo.com to HTTPS:

```
<rule name="Add WWW prefix to foo.com and use HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^foo\.com" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.foo.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
```

And for bar.com:

```
<rule name="Force NonHTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{REQUEST_URI}" />
</rule>
```

Take a look at `stopProcessing` attribute in the first rule. It should stop processing of next rules when the foo.com will be matched. This won't allow "Force NonHTTPS" rule to trigger.

Comment: Thanks for your response, bar.com is not redirected to https and this is OK but foo.com gives me this error:
"This page isn’t working
foo.com redirected you too many times."